# Authorize attribute authorizes on null

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I manually manage users and their logins. I use a modelbinder to pass logged in users to controllers as parameters. Now some controllers and methods use the `Authorize` attribute to restrict access, but authorizes `null` instead of only `Account` objects.

This happens for examples when an Account is removed, but the user was still logged in. This is the modelbinder:

```
public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
            HttpCookie authCookie = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
            if (authCookie != null)
            {
                var authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
                int userId = int.Parse(authTicket.UserData.Split(',')[0]);
                var userRepository = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IUserRepository)) as IUserRepository;
                return userRepository.FindById(userId) as Account;
            }
            return null;
}
```

The repository returns null because the account doesn't exist anymore, but it's still authorized. This is the login:

```
 private void LoginUser(Account account, bool remeberMe)
        {
            string role = ObjectContext.GetObjectType(account.GetType()).Name;
            String userData = account.UserId + "," + role;

            //clear any other tickets that are already in the response
            Response.Cookies.Clear();
            DateTime expiryDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);

            //create the FAT
            var authenticationTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, account.FirstName, DateTime.Now,
                expiryDate, remeberMe, userData, string.Empty);

            //create cookie
            var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
                FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authenticationTicket));
            if (remeberMe)
            {
                cookie.Expires = expiryDate;
            }

            //finish
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            HttpContext.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(account.FullName),
                new[] { role });
        }
```

I think it's still authorized because the HttpContext.User is still set. What's the best way to reset the HttpContext.User and delete the cookies of removed users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using role based authentication then the most graceful way of handling it would be to revoke the roles of the user. They would still be logged in, but unable to access the privileged information.

Otherwise, you would have to create a deleted flag and create some sort of action filter, custom authorize attribute, or method of checking it for each request and logging them out manually if this check fails.

If you are using the new ASP.NET identity (it appears as if you are not and are using a custom forms auth), you can actually regenerate the security stamp since it uses that to determine if the credentials of the user have changed on each request.

Comment: Thanks. I think logging them out manually is the easiest and the modelbinder is a very good place to do that, but is that possible there? And how? FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); didn't fix this.

Comment: Are you using the Authorize attribute? It would make the most sense to extend it and add a check for a disabled flag there

Comment: Well, the row is removed completely, so it doesn't have flags. But how do I actually remove all this users sessions and cookies?

Comment: Maybe instead of checking a deleted flag you could just see if that user's row exists, if not then force the user to LogOut.

Comment: Yes indeed. I already found out how to log them out, but I don't want to have double code. I'd like to call the logout method of the controller from the modelbinder, but this is not recommended?

Comment: I think it would make more sense to use an AuthorizeAttribute or an action filter, but it could work. What if they access a HttpGet page that doesn't hit the model binder but is still showing some records of some sort?

Comment: OK, I'll look into that.